# Does SQL Server Express 2008 work on local networks?

Tags: sql-server-2008-express

I want to connect multiple clients at the same time to a specific database (eg. `mydb.mdf`) on SQL Server Express 2008 in a local network (LAN). Is it possible or I have to install SQL Server 2008?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have SQL Server 2008 Express have clients conect over the network. Just enable the tcp/ip and/or named pipes protocol (if not enabled) for the service and restart the service.

Comment: Is there any helpful link for how to enable the tcp/ip protocol for the service?

Comment: The Express version should come with a start menu entry for the service configuration manager. Try Start > All programmes > SQL Server 2008 > Configuration Tools >

Answer (score 1):

Yes its possible.

Download SQL Server 2008 R2 if you face permission issues.

Answer (score 1):

There's no problems access Express over the network; you might just need to enable it. Beyond that, you can check it's limitations on Microsft's [SQL Server website](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/product-info/compare.aspx).